# hook_form_alter setting select list #options key allow attributes per option

Tags: forms

I have a select list that I am populating $form['field_my_field']['und']['#options'] in a hook_form_alter.

I was wondering what a good way to set a data attribute per each option would be. I've thought about adding some inline javascript to add it after it's rendered, but I want to do this with PHP and preferably within the hook_form_alter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [theme_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_select/7) which is the one that constructs and styles the Drupal Form API's select type. It uses the [form_select_options](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_select_options/7) function do create the `<option>` tags.

So you would need to override *theme_select* and replace the *form_select_options* function with your own.

Basically, copy the functions and it's content, rename them and do your modifications.